# How to install asset in Symfony2 manually?

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig, assets

When I try to install assets using this command:

```
 assets:install web --symlink
```

I get this exception:

[InvalidArgumentException]
The symlink() function is not available on your system. You need to install
the assets without the --symlink option.

That is because I'm using windows XP.
So I tried to solve this installing Link Shell Extension: http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html#introduction

and now the problem is that I do not know which files need to be a symbolic link.

I tried doing the folder "MyBundle/resources/public"  a  symbolic to the folder "web" of my project, and it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The windows system does not support symbolic links. It copy / paste files instead. So you can only used this command :

```
assets:install web
```

or

```
assets:install
```